# Как вывести числа по диагонали?

Tags: delphi

Помогите, пожалуйста, выполнить задание в Delphi:

1. Создать приложение: расположить на форму таблицу 10х10. При щелчке на кнопку "Заполнить таблицу" ячейки таблицы заполняются числами от 1 до 200 с шагом 2(1,3,5,7,9 и т.д).
2. Вывести числа вспомогательной диагонали.(числа вывести в Edit)

Таблицу я заполнила! Но не пойму, какое условие нужно чтобы вывести числа диагонали в Edit?

Answer (score 3):

Значит так, зная из истории начала своего программирования существуют свойства для двумерного массива имеющего равное кол-во столбцов и строк.

**I - строка**

**J - колонка**

**N - кол-во элементов в строке**, а точнее если мы имеем двоичную матрицу, а это та в которой кол-во строк = кол-ву столбцов. В твоем случае это число 10

далее

```
    if I=J then элемент расположен на главной диагонали
    if I>J then элемент расположен под главной диагональю
    if I>J then элемент расположен над главной диагональю
if I+J=N+1 then побочная диагональ
if I+J<N+1 then над побочной
if I+J>N+1 then под побочной
```

Эти условия проверять в цикле

```
for I:=1 to N do
  for J:=1 to N do
   Begin
    {условие}
     //ну и делать что нужно
   End;
```

Comment: еще можно принять ответ.

Comment: Ни чего не поняла!

Comment: обновил ответ, включай логику.

Comment: Я блондинка-какая логика)Что после then??

Comment: Блондинка программист? ;D

Comment: Ну это сильно сказано!студентка я)помогите,объясните мне,пжалста,как числа по диагонали вывести в Edit?

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var i,j,k:integer;
begin
k:=1;
for i:=0 to 9 do
for j:=0 to 9 do
begin
stringGrid1.Cells[j,i]:=inttostr(2*k-1);
inc(k);
end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var i,j,n:integer;
begin
for I:=0 to N do
  for J:=0 to N do
   Begin
     if I=J then
    {что здесь должно быть?И ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ ВООБЩЕ?(}
   End;

Comment: Люди,не бросайте меня!!!

Comment: **

for I:=0 to 9 do
    Edit1.Text = Edit1.Text + stringGrid1.Cells[I,I] + ' ';

Так?)

Но это главная диагональ. Побочная - вместо `[I,I]` => `[I, 9-I]`.

Comment: Спасибо, тебе!Всё круть!Всё работает!

Comment: Абалдеть... @AlexWindHope жжоте батюшка. про блондинку-программиста.

Ух как, один ответ и куча комментов.

@Ирина  
>Я блондинка-какая логика)Что после then??

Это убило просто! :D